# Show character cont in input box as user types

Tags: limits, text

two quick questions involving character limits in text fields.

1) Is it possible to not include spaces when determining whether inputted text exceeds the character limit?

2) Is it possible to have the current character count display in a text input field as a user is typing?

Thank you!

Comment: A space is still a character from the perspective of text-field limits.  It takes up the same amount of memory/space as a visible character or symbol in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question:

> Is it possible to not include spaces when determining whether inputted
>   text exceeds the character limit?

HomerJ sums it up pretty nicely with his comment here:

> A space is still a character from the perspective of text-field
>   limits. It takes up the same amount of memory/space as a visible
>   character or symbol in a string.

With regard to your second question:

Is it possible to have the current character count display in a text input field as a user is typing?

The answer is no... Kind of.

- Salesforce does do this when you're close to the limit already as
  part of it's standard functionality
  [image]
- Consider a Visualforce/Apex Form?
- You could do something like the following:

  1. Create a number field like Text_Field_Total_Characters__c
  2. Create a formula field of number type like Character_Count__c with syntax `LEN( Text_field__c )`
  3. Create another formula field called something like Character_Left__c and subtract 2 from 1.

  Although I doubt this is what you're after

Really I'm just throwing some ideas at you, but ultimately you really can't do this from the standard UI.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the point 2 of your question, you can do that using javascript.
I created the following JS Fiddle to give you an idea.

https://jsfiddle.net/es1ns30L/1/

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is it possible to not include spaces when determining whether inputted text exceeds the character limit?

No. The database counts each character as a character. If you're using Visualforce/etc you could strip out the characters before they're saved to the database, otherwise they will count against the total character limit for the field.

> 2) Is it possible to have the current character count display in a text input field as a user is typing?

In the standard UI, no. If you're willing to write some Visualforce, you can do so in a fairly easy manner. [@AAU](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/14779/aau) wrote up a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/es1ns30L/1/) for this to get you started. If you wanted to, you could also write code to actively prevent exceeding the limit or stripping out spaces, etc.